# Scipy: Large file for fitting gamma distribution

Tags: python, scipy, hdf5

I need to calculate the gamma distribution parameters for a packet capture's TTL distribution. The capture's size is about 14 GBytes.

At first, I extracted all TTL values from the files by using Wireshark's `tshark` tool:

`tshark -r file -Y ip -T fields -e ip.ttl > ttl_values.txt`

The resulting file consists of TTL values (one per line) and is approx. 700 MByte. If I try to load the values by using `genfromtxt`, the process gets killed due to memory exhaustion.

```
data = np.genfromtxt('ttl_values.txt')
```

However, if I use a much smaller TTL file (approx. 56K), it works fine. I read that `h5df` and `tables` are recommended for processing large files, thus I converted the file ttl_values.txt into a h5p file as follow:

```
filepath = 'random_vals'
out_file = filepath + '.h5p'
h5 = pd.HDFStore(out_file, 'w')
it = pd.read_csv(filepath + '.txt', iterator=True, chunksize=100000)
for i, chunk in enumerate(it):
        h5.append('data', chunk)
h5.close()
```

But I cannot find any information on how to use this data now for the `gamma.fit` method:

```
data = # use data from ttl_values.txt
fit_alpha, fit_log, fit_beta=stats.gamma.fit(data)
print('alpha: ', fit_alpha)
print('log: ', fit_log)
print('beta: ', fit_beta)
```

1. Must the data be supplied in the form (ttl-value, packet-count) or is my input file consisting of each packet's TTL (one per line) fine?
2. Is the approach with `h5df` and `tables` generally suitable?
3. How can I read the file to use it as an data object for `gamma.fit`?

Comment: Hdf-data can usually accessed just like numpy arrays (depending on the library, but both common libs should support this). Check the docs as i'm quite sure one of the first examples is showing this kind of accessing. I would be more worried about the fitting itself with such huge data. I don't think, that the implementation will be able to do that (probably based on scipy.optimize; but i'm unsure which kind of optimizer is used; first-order vs. second-order based). I fear, that for this amount of data you would need some customized fitting-implementation tailored for the size (probably online)

Comment: The process for fitting the gamma distribution is running now for 6 hours, I am not giving up the hope that it finishes successfully ;-) However, in case it does not work - can you suggest me any alternative solution being able to process large data? Maybe in C++ (for better performance)?

Comment: It's not a problem with the language. It's a problem of algorithms/approaches. If it's using scipy.optimize which i think, than it's already implemented in C/C++/Fortran (depending on the optimizer chosen). It's likely, that the parameters/approache is tuned for a smaller scale of data. I also don't think, that you gain a lot with that much data. You can easily check this with some kind of cross-validation. Fit on 1% and compare the distribution, fit on 2% and do it again (very high-level description)